# How to only select dates in past in ng-bs-daterangepicker?

Tags: angularjs, date, datepicker, momentjs

I need to make sure selected dates on ng-bs-daterangepicker are in the past.

Here is an example:

I have FROM and TO dates, I need to select dates to show in a graph. 
With the first picker I need to set the "FROM" date, which has to be in the past and on the second picker I need select the "TO" date, this date should not be less than the FROM date, neither greater than today's date.

I tried this:

```
<input
type="daterange"
ng-model="dates"
format="L"
separator="/"
max-date={{todyDateRangeChart}};
opens="left"
/>
```

and in ctrl

```
$scope.todyDateRangeChart = new Date();
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/aboygJoxdHUmh65xgIDX?p=preview) it is in Plunker

Comment: max-date is not working?

Comment: Hi, no they don't working

Comment: There are too many problems in your plunkr. Can you get your plnkkr to reproduce the problem. It does not even have AngularJS library added.

Comment: @bhantol i edit plunker... take a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed max-date.

They seem to worked only with string dates.

```
 <input
 type="daterange" 
 ng-model="dates" 
 format="L" 
 separator="/" 
 min-date="{{minDate}}" 
 max-date="{{maxDate}}"
 opens="left" />
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.minDate = '2013-08-01';
$scope.maxDate = '2013-09-30';
```

Few additional changes to the controller: I also changed the order or scripts - angular is just a bit before ng-bootstrap-datepicker. And added the controller as ng-controller.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/12zPeSW46VN8jmTDB3Uo?p=preview)

Comment: thnx for this, but how to get this to work "With the first picker I need to set the "FROM" date, which has to be in the past and on the second picker I need select the "TO" date, this date should not be less than the FROM date, neither greater than today's date."

Comment: The plnkr does exactly the same going back year 2013